# No response from the sensor when connecting to the server

Tags: python, sockets, sensors

So i am trying to get the data from a pressure sensor Boditrak. It is connected via USB but I am not sure which port is it using... When I am connecting it I have this Data Port [this is how I see it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NmcX.png). It has its own software, but I need to get it through Python.
This is the code that I wrote:

```
import socket

serverAddress = 'http://localhost/api'
serverPort = 63342
bufferSize = 4096


def connect(self):
  global s
  s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  s.settimeout(10)

  print("Connecting to server")
  s.connect((serverAddress, serverPort))
  print("Connected to server\n")

  response = s.recv(bufferSize)
  print(response.decode("utf-8"))
```

Now I am not sure I am doing the right thing... but I am not sure how am I supposed to get it. Any help is appreciated.
Also the data looks like this [accessed in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP6M8.png) and I get every second a new frame

When I am running the script in terminal I get nothing.
When I am reading the manual it says: "The DataPort device communicates with client devices (PC, tablet, phones) over a wifi network using a REST API. The primary role of the DataPort device is to scan one or more Boditrak sensor mats at a prescribed frequency and store those readings in a buffer"

Also do I need to have a server side and a client side? If yes, how is it supposed to look like?

Thank you!

PS. This is the live data that I want to get [image: image with continues data]
Maybe I should call this GET /api/sse HTTP/1.1. But how?

For example, i took another approach but still no answer...

```
import socket
 from urllib import parse

def connect():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    url = parse.urlparse('http://localhost/api')
    s.connect((url[1], 80))
    msg = 'GET' + 'http://localhost/api' + 'HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'
    s.send(msg.encode('utf-8'))
    response = s.recv(4096)
    data = response.decode('utf-8')
    print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

I get the following answer:

```
b''
```

UPDATE: I get some data now. Here is the code:

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit

def connect():
#create an INET, STREAMing socket
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error:
        print('Failed to create socket')
        sys.exit()
    print('Socket Created')

    host = '127.0.0.1';
    port = 80;

    try:
        remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )
    except socket.gaierror:
        #could not resolve
        print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
        sys.exit()

    #Connect to remote server
    s.connect((remote_ip , port))
    print('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

    #Send some data to remote server
message2 = b"GET /api/sse HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
    try:
        # Set the whole string
        s.sendall(message2)
    except socket.error:
        # Send failed
        print('Send failed')
        sys.exit()
    print('Message send successfully')

    # Now receive data
    reply2 = s.recv(16384)
    print('Frames:', reply2.decode())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

And the reply:

```
Socket Created
Socket Connected to 127.0.0.1 on ip 127.0.0.1


Message send successfully
Frames: Access-control-allow-origin: *
Access-control-allow-methods: GET, OPTIONS
Content-type: application/json
Cache-control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Content-Length: 2583

{
"device":{ "class":"Boditrak DataPort", "name":"DataPort-******", "id":"*********", "address":"127.0.0.1", "model":"wia" },
"sensors":[ { "name":"**********", "columns":32, "rows":32, "width":470, "height":470, "minimum":0, "maximum":200, "units":"mmHg" } ],
"frames":[ { "id":719, "time":"2021-04-19 16:19:47.041", "readings":[ [ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
,1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,3,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,1 ] ] } ],
"filters":{ "spot":false, "smooth":false, "noise":false },
"time":"2021-04-19 16:19:47.097",
"frequency":27000,
"yield":false,
"calibrated":true,
"sensorsRequired":0,
"others":[ ]
}
```

I have to figure it out how to get it continuously. Still sees the last frame...

Last update!

```
import socket   #for sockets
import sys  #for exit
import json
import time

t_end = time.time() + 60 * 0.2


def connect():
#create an INET, STREAMing socket
    try:
        global s
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    except socket.error:
        print('Failed to create socket')
        sys.exit()
    print('Socket Created')

    host = '127.0.0.1';
    port = 80;

    try:
        remote_ip = socket.gethostbyname( host )
    except socket.gaierror:
        #could not resolve
        print('Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting')
        sys.exit()

    #Connect to remote server
    s.connect((remote_ip , port))
    print('Socket Connected to ' + host + ' on ip ' + remote_ip)

    message2 = b"GET /api/sse HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"
    try:
        # Set the whole string
        s.sendall(message2)
    except socket.error:
        # Send failed
        print('Send failed')
        sys.exit()
    print('Message send successfully')

   
    while time.time() < t_end:
        reply2 = s.recv(4096).decode('utf-8')
        response = json.dumps(reply2)
        print(response)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

This code is working and it is giving me data in real time. I encountered problems with an error: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine -- and after I deactivated my antivirus it works.

Heading

Comment: Which address do you enter in Chrome?

Comment: http://localhost/api/sse                         here I get all the live data. (see the screenshot of live data in the post)

Comment: Surely Chrome doesn't use port 63342 if not told to, does it? Why do you use that port in the Python code?

Comment: Well then which one should I use? How do I check which Port all these data are stored to?

Comment: You didn't answer my question. However, if a HTTP request from Chrome works, the approach in your "answer" below (which should've rather been added to the question post) should also work; perhaps just the missing spaces between `GET`, `http://localhost/api` and `HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n` prevent that.

Comment: I chose that one because when I looked on CMD it was the only one listening on that IP address. You are right. I modified the initial post with the code below.

Comment: Now, did you try with the missing spaces inserted?

Comment: Yes. But I get nothing. No error, just blank space..

Comment: I'm puzzled. Could you `print(msg.encode())` in the script and show the output?

Comment: Yes. I am getting: b'GET http://localhost/api HTTP/1.1'                But now I am getting this error when I am asking for the response = s.recv(4096): ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine

Comment: Hm - it should be `b'GET … HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'`; where are the CR/NL pairs gone? (It's rather a rhetorical question.) Without them, it can't work.

Comment: I am getting data now. Check the update. Now I just have to make it continuously

Comment: Congratulation! - Now, `s.recv()` is called just once; perhaps call it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your script runs in the terminal you'll need to tell python to execute your method. To do that you can use an [import guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do). Add the following to the bottom of your file. This'll ensure that your `connect` method executes.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

Given that you can access your data stream through the browser, you could make your life easier by using the `requests` library instead of working with sockets. It has the potential to save time by handling low level socket work for you.

For example:

```
import time
import requests

def connect():
    url = 'http://localhost/api'
    wait_time = 1
    while True:
        time.sleep(wait_time)  # wait for 1s
        r = requests.get(url)  # get data
        # print output to console
        ​print(r.text) # text based output
        print(r.json())  # json output <- probably what you need given the screenshot

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect()
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to use socket?